# Why is my glob in my npm script not working?

Tags: node.js, glob, prettier-eslint

I am trying to create a regex glob for an NPM script. This is what I have:

```
"format": "prettier-eslint --write \"{,!(node_modules|cypressTests)/**/}*.{js,json,vue}\""
```

And this currently formats all .js, .json, and .vue files that are NOT in the node_modules folder or in the cypressTests folder.

**The below is my problem:**

The `cypressTests` folder ALSO contains a `node_modules` folder that I do not want to format. How can I exclude `./cypressTests/node_modules` just like I am currently doing for the folder `./node_modules`?

I tried like this and this does not work. It then excludes pretty much everything in the entire project for some reason:

```
"format": "prettier-eslint --write \"{,!(node_modules|cypressTests/node_modules)/**/}*.{js,json,vue}\""
```

Comment: This `!` should be inside the `()` probably

Comment: I just tried `(!node_modules|cypressTests/node_modules)` and `(!node_modules|!cypressTests/node_modules)` and still didn't work. It excludes the entire project except for 9 files.

Comment: "Regex" and "glob" are two different things.

Comment: Oh my bad, its actually a glob. I thought they were similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier has an easier solution to ignore files. You can make a [.prettierignore file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) (which uses [.gitignore syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)) to ignore files when prettifying. The file should be placed in the root directory of your project. I believe the syntax inside the file in your case would be:

```
**/node_modules
```

Which is actually what prettier ignores by default (among some other source-control folder exclusions)-- so unless you already have a `.prettierignore` file, all `node_modules` folders should already be excluded from prettification.

The command would then simply be:

```
"format": "prettier-eslint --write \"**/*.{js,json,vue}\""
```

or if you want your `.prettierignore` file to be somewhere else:

```
"format": "prettier-eslint --ignore-path <path-to-ignore-file> --write \"**/*.{js,json,vue}\""
```

If this solution doesn't work for you and you need to use the glob method, I wasn't quite able to figure that out, but [this website](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob) was handy for testing globs.

Comment: Your solution worked perfect. I struggled with the glob for countless hours. Different glob testers would even show me different results so I'm happy to use .prettierignore instead. thanks!

Comment: @mcool No problem, I'm glad I could help! Good luck with the project! :)